# Bootstrap conflics with custom CSS transition - How to find + fix the conlicting css rule?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am trying to add a custom CSS `transition` to my existing `Bootstrap 3` based project. A simple `flex` container which holds a value `input` and a `select` field. `jQuery` is used to add a `.hidden` class to the `input` field when the first `select` value is picked. This class changes the `flex-base` property of the `input` field which should than be hidden using a transition. When another value is picked the field is shown again.

Everything works fine when I use a simple test HTML file. But as soon as I add the `bootstrap.css` link in the header, the transition does not work any more. The `select` field still hides/shows but without a transition.

**How can I find out which part of `bootstrap.css` is responsible and fix this problem?** I already spend hours digging through the bootstrap files but without any success so far.

---

Select value A from the select field in the following examples to see the problem...

Working Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/gd03sjtn

Fiddle with Bootstrap (does not work): https://jsfiddle.net/gd03sjtn/1

Two snippets demonstrating it working / not working (blocked by bootstrap css)

```js
$(function() {
  var $typeSelect = $('#typeSelect');
  var $valueSpinner = $('#valueInput');

  $typeSelect.change(function() {
    if ($typeSelect.val() == "0") {
      $typeSelect.addClass('red');
      $valueSpinner.parent().addClass('hidden');
    } else {
      $typeSelect.removeClass('red');
      $valueSpinner.parent().removeClass('hidden');
    }
  });
});
```

```css
.container {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  flex-wrap: nowrap;
}

.container select {
  flex-grow: 10;
}

.container select.red {
  background: red;
}

.container .spinner {
  flex-grow: 0;
  flex-basis: 30%;
  transition: flex-basis 500ms ease-in-out;
}

.container .spinner.hidden {
  flex-basis: 0%;
}

.container .spinner input.valueInput {
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<!-- Remove Bootstrap.css to make this working -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="container">
  <span class="spinner">
                <input id="valueInput" value="205" class="valueInput">
            </span>

  <select id="typeSelect">
    <option value="0">A</option>
    <option value="1">B</option>
    <option value="2">C</option>
    <option value="3" selected="selected">D</option>
    <option value="4">E</option>
  </select>
</div>
```

```js
$(function() {
  var $typeSelect = $('#typeSelect');
  var $valueSpinner = $('#valueInput');

  $typeSelect.change(function() {
    if ($typeSelect.val() == "0") {
      $typeSelect.addClass('red');
      $valueSpinner.parent().addClass('hidden');
    } else {
      $typeSelect.removeClass('red');
      $valueSpinner.parent().removeClass('hidden');
    }
  });
});
```

```css
.container {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  flex-wrap: nowrap;
}

.container select {
  flex-grow: 10;
}

.container select.red {
  background: red;
}

.container .spinner {
  flex-grow: 0;
  flex-basis: 30%;
  transition: flex-basis 500ms ease-in-out;
}

.container .spinner.hidden {
  flex-basis: 0%;
}

.container .spinner input.valueInput {
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<!-- Remove Bootstrap.css to make this working -->
<!-- <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css"> -->
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="container">
  <span class="spinner">
                <input id="valueInput" value="205" class="valueInput">
            </span>

  <select id="typeSelect">
    <option value="0">A</option>
    <option value="1">B</option>
    <option value="2">C</option>
    <option value="3" selected="selected">D</option>
    <option value="4">E</option>
  </select>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is that you're using the same class name as one from bootstrap:

```
hidden { display: none!important }
```

so your `spinner` flex panel isn't shrinking to `flex-basis: 0%` - it's disappearing completely, immediately - the key parting being immediately.

---

> How can I find out which part of bootstrap.css is responsible and fix this problem?

First, try different class names in your own css - I changed `hidden` to `hiddenx` in your js+css and it started working ok again, so that was the issue.

Second, look in the Elements/Styles tab/sub-tab of developer tools (F12) to see what's changing.

Also, partly knowing what styles bootstrap uses, knowing that `hidden` makes something, well, hidden, so I knew from that (after wasting time looking at the `select`) that it was bootstrap class it was a case of determining (in the styles tab) what it was adding (rather than wade through the bootstrap css (no thanks))

Answer (score 1):

When you make a request to get all css rules for bootstrap:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
```

this link in the header will merge all others configurations in your css...

**Solution:**

Download the compiled bootstrap.min.css and modify to use just what you need!

https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.1/getting-started/download/

Comment: While this *is* an option, I would recommend it unless you a) need to micro-manage what parts you get and (more importantly) b) already know which parts to include/exclude.   Doing this will likely come back to bite you when you later try to use a class that the docs say is there, SO questions say is there, but you don't realise you've excluded in your own personal download.  Maybe something to do as final steps to optimise your otherwise completed application.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest to use the developer tools (F12) of firefox or chrome. In the "elements" tab (this is the chrome wording - not sure how it is called in firefox, but you can find the same areas there) find your element for which the css transition should work. Click on it and then look on the right side in the style-area. You see all styles that apply. The style with the highest precendence selector is on top. If you are not sure which value for which css attribute is finally use on your elemente the mpve over to the Computed tab.

In both areas you see the applied styles and from which stylesheet and from which line within they come.